# PHP - transform value from XML field to HTML field with elements which is repeating?

Tags: php, html, xml

I have xml field `$xmlstring` with value;

```
'<result>
  <customerAccount xmlns="http://www.ibm.com>
    <AccountStatus xmlns="">Due</AccountStatus>

    <ComponentCustomerAccount xmlns="">
      <Name>ADSL</Name>
      <CharacteristicValue>
        <Characteristic>
          <Name>Balance</Name>
        </Characteristic>
        <Value>0.0</Value>
      </CharacteristicValue>
      <CharacteristicValue>
        <Characteristic>
          <Name>Date</Name>
        </Characteristic>
        <Value>21.10.1990</Value>
      </CharacteristicValue>
      <AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
    </ComponentCustomerAccount>

    <ComponentCustomerAccount xmlns="">
      <Name>IPTV</Name>
      <CharacteristicValue>
        <Characteristic>
          <Name>Balance</Name>
        </Characteristic>
        <Value>100</Value>
      </CharacteristicValue>
      <CharacteristicValue>
        <Characteristic>
          <Name>Date</Name>
        </Characteristic>
        <Value>21.10.1990</Value>
      </CharacteristicValue>
      <AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
    </ComponentCustomerAccount>


  </customerAccount>
</result>';
```

I want to display in HTML field within table:

```
NAME       STATUS     VALUE

ADSL       ACTIVE     0.0
IPTV       ACTIVE     100
```

As you can see I have some elements which are repeating.
ComponentCustomerAccount is repeating and I can have multiple elements.
I do not need first AccountStatus element but I need AccountStatus element within ComponentCustomerAccount.
Also I need first element Name within ComponentCustomerAccount element.

```
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

    $html = "<table>";
    $html .= "<tr><th>Account Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Amount</th></tr>";
    foreach($xml->customerAccount as $cust) {

     $html .= "<tr><th>" . $cust->Name .
 "</th><th>" . $cust->AccountStatus. "</th><th>" . $cust->Value . "</th></tr>";


    }

    $html .= "</table>";
```

But I am getting blank output.
What do I have to change?
Thank you

Comment: your customer account that you iterate through contains only one column . but there are three ComponentCustomerAccount you should iterate

Comment: hello thak you for response. I have two ComponentCustomerAccount. SItuation is the same when I try to iterate situation is the same. Can ou maybe give me some code example? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML is missing a close quote in `<customerAccount xmlns="http://www.ibm.com>`.  Once you fix that, you need to iterate over `ComponentCustomerAccount` inside of the loop:

```
foreach($xml->customerAccount as $ca) {
    foreach ($ca->ComponentCustomerAccount as $cust) {
        $html .= "<tr><th>" . $cust->Name
        . "</th><th>" . $cust->AccountStatus. "</th><th>"
        . $cust->CharacteristicValue->Value . "</th></tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: But Value is inside <CharacteristicValue> element ?? can you take it ust with $cust?

Comment: if I my just one more little update regarding this? you will notice that I have two CustomerValue elements now. How should I retrieve Value for first and how for second? I will update now in my question

Comment: of course I will add in my HTML table additional columnn for Date value in CaracteristicValue. Thank you and sorry really for your time